# Is it safe to return an ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> that wraps S3Object.getObjectContent() in REST controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm developing an Spring Boot Application, that should allow users to download files indirectly from Amazon S3 via specified application REST interface. For this purpose I have an REST-Controller, that returns an InputStreamResource to the user like following:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/download/{fileId}")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFileById(@PathVariable("fileId") Integer fileId) {
    Optional<LocalizedFile> fileForDownload = fileService.getConcreteFileForDownload(fileId);

    if (!fileForDownload.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileForDownload.get().getFilename())
            .body(new InputStreamResource(fileService.download(fileForDownload.get())));
}
```

Download method in file service looks like this:

```java
@Override
public InputStream download(LocalizedFile file) {
    S3Object obj = s3client.getObject(bucketName, file.getFilename());
    return obj.getObjectContent();
}
```

My concern here is that this input stream from Amazon SDK could not be closed explicitly in controller. There is a following [warning in AWS documentation of the getObjectContent() method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#getObjectContent--), that makes me suspicious about success of my approach described above:

> If you retrieve an S3Object, you should close this input stream as
>   soon as possible, because the object contents aren't buffered in
>   memory and stream directly from Amazon S3. Further, failure to close
>   this stream can cause the request pool to become blocked.

Therefore my question:
Is it safe to return an `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>` in controller? Will this InputStream from `S3Object.getObjectContent()` be closed automatically after successful download? So far my approach has worked successfully, but I'm not so sure about possible future consequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660203/5305936), that should be applicable to my question.

Tl;dr version: Spring MVC [handles the closing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java#L139) of the given input stream, so my approach described above should be safe.